# Collectd on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rrdtool, statsd, collectd

We have instances setup in an autoscale group on AWS. We want to collect the metrics in order to determine our scalability needs. Collectd, so far I know that it collects the stats in the same machine and puts it all in RRD files. However, in a scenario of an autoscale cluster, if another instance is spawned and assuming the AMI from which it has been spawned already has collectd, how are we supposed to gather the stats of that second instance in the group? It might just stay up for five to six minutes and go down, but we would need the logs before it goes down. Any way by which we can club these logs for the same cluster or something similar? Or if collectd can make it report somewhere online?

Comment: I would look into installing the AWS CloudWatch Logs agent on these servers and streaming the logs to CloudWatch.

Comment: @MarkB Yes that is a valid option but cloudwatch takes time to refresh. It is unable to give second by second details. There is a possibility on missing out on important info in such a case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. This can be done by using the client-server architecture of collectd. More details can be found [here](http://www.tecmint.com/configure-collectd-as-central-monitoring-server-for-clients/)